# JQuery Mobile: Event when page is opened in Multi-page scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I am using a multi-page scenario in jQuery mobile and I would like to trigger backend calls whenever the corresponding page is displayed to the user. I am missing a good point to do it. This is how my code looks like:

```
<head>
    <script>
        $(document).on('swipeleft', '.ui-page', function (event) {
            if (event.handled !== true) {
                var nextpage = $.mobile.activePage.next('[data-role="page"]');
                // swipe using id of next page if exists
                if (nextpage.length > 0) {
                    $.mobile.changePage(nextpage, { transition: "slide", reverse: false }, true, true);
                }
                event.handled = true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <page data-role="page" id="weekChartPage">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
            <h1>Charts</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <canvas id="weekChart"></canvas>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="b" data-position="fixed" data-id="footer">
            <h1>Footer</h1>
        </div>
    </page>

    <page data-role="page" id="monthChartPage">
        <div data-role="content">
            <canvas id="monthChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </page>

    <page data-role="page" id="dayChartPage">
        <div role="main" class="ui-content">
            <canvas id="dayChart"></canvas>
        </div>
    </page>
</body>
```

Now I am missing the right event to attach to when the new page has been changed to to trigger the corresponding backend call. I thought of reading the ID of the current page and trigger a backend call to display the matching chart.

Any hint?

Thanks

Comment: Listen to `pagecontainershow`.

Comment: here is the "holy grail" of JQM page events: [jQuery Mobile “Page” Events + Extra](https://jqmtricks.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/jquery-mobile-page-events-extra/)